# Printing number of lines with in shell with echo

Tags: shell

I know that the simplest way to print out the specific value of line/bytes/words is to use `wc -l < filename.sh`, but when i try to use it in conjunction with the echo command, it's printing the physical command itself and not the output.

My intended output is "this file has x lines", with x being number of lines, but when i try to do things like `echo "this line has" wc -l < filename.sh "lines"`, it's printing the command itself. I've also tried this without breaking the quotation, among several other things.

is it just the command itself that's not applicable alongside echo, or am i missing something extremely obvious here?

Comment: In additions to `$(command)` providing **command substitution** you will also see *backticks* used, e.g. `\`command\`` (the older and somewhat deprecated manner of accomplishing the same thing). Also, don't worry, there is plenty more that is extremely obvious to miss in *man bash*...

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "this line has $(wc -l < filename.sh) lines"
```

Answer (score 1):

`printf` is versatile:

```
printf 'this file has %s lines\n' $(wc -l < filename.sh)
```

`$(command)` converts the output of `command` into an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
echo "this file has `wc -l < filename.sh | awk '{print $1}'` lines"
```

Explanation:

`wc -l < filename.sh` retrieves the line number of the file

`awk '{print $1}'` prints the number without any blanks

``` `` ``` means executing the command first in order to get the result

Answer (score 0):

Without any subshell or pipe, `awk` have an inbuilt variable `NR` which holds the number of record in the input file. Print is written inside `END` block to print the result at the end else, it will print the line number of each line.

```
 awk 'END{print "This line has " NR " lines" }' file
```